# Opinion Based Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, opinion-based

I've recently asked this question: [What are the advantages of server side Blazor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482506/what-are-the-advantages-of-server-side-blazor-app)

It got flagged as opinion based pretty fast, even though I intended to ask for specific benefits of using a framework server-side. 
I've read through the guidelines for "Good opinion based questions", but  can't think of rewording this in any way that will help.

As last resort, there was a suggestion to ask a question on META, hence here I am.

Should I just close or delete the question? 
How can I edit it in order to make it less "opinion based" sounding?

Comment: There isn't really much you can do; the question *is* opinionated.  There's no way to fix it, and preserve the intent of the question.

Comment: What is and isn't a benefit is an opinion.

Comment: I'm really on the fence about this one. Certainly we don't want questions & associated answers that are based purely on opinion with minimal basis on objectively verifiable facts. However concepts such as benefits & advantages *are* possible to objectively characterize provided the goal is well defined (ie shared understanding & no shifting goalposts). For example, consider many of the questions regarding security. Perhaps I'm the odd one out here, but I actually interpret his question as asking "what is the point of doing this" or "why would we want this" which seems fairly reasonable to me.

Comment: @AnOccasionalCashew, That was my thinking as well. In my mind the linked question was along the lines of "What is the benefit of removing late bindings from VB.NET code". Sure, there could be an opinion answer, but there also could be a good, referenced, "provable" answer.  I was hoping to get the latter. Nevertheless, the consensus seems to point otherwise, and I understand its point. Will ask moderators to close/delete the linked question. This one will stay, in order to help other poor souls in the future, hopefully :)

Comment: @AnOccasionalCashew "benefits" are in the eye of the beholder. For instance, I used to live in Minnesota, and people would hype the benefits of the "polar bear plunge", where people would make a hole in the ice and jump into the freezing water below. I could find no benefit in stopping my heart and risking hypothermia and declined to join in. The trick is to include exactly what those objective criteria are that should be used when answering the question. For instance, if someone could cite a study that detailed exactly what benefit I received from the plunge, that would be a fair question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Agreed. In your example, so long as you clearly define that `benefit == scientifically established improvement to overall health` then I don't see a problem with the question. However, the current accepted answer and vote distribution would seem to indicate that this view is not shared by the community at large; I'm not clear on what the current consensus is for where to draw the line.

Comment: @AnOccasionalCashew, +6/-13 on this question. +3/-6 on the original.  I am a bit surprised that this question got heavily downvoted without being marked as duplicate, off topic, etc...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I agree. Yet, StackOverflow doesn't always ban option questions, mainly bad ones that produce low quality answers (at least according to their guidelines). I thought the answers on the original questions were helpful, informative, and, well, "good". But then again, this is only my opinion :)
Regardless, I learned something new, and hopefully it will help others.

Comment: It drives me nuts how flag-happy people have become on this platform. You'll get a question closed or downvoted and the system doesn't require those people to provide an ounce of feedback. They are basically just rewarded for being lazy. If you go search on the site there are tons of questions that didn't get closed. At this point in time, it's just prevented me from caring to contribute to the site. I will no longer ask questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not much you can do about this question, unfortunately.  It's just *too* opinionated and open-ended.  The best people you could've posed this question to were in the room when the presentation happened, since they would've been able to give you an answer about the pros and cons of this new technology.

All the rest of us can do is wave at blog posts and documentation and *guess* at an answer, which isn't the quality of question we want to have here.

Comment: I'd argue that as a potential answerer if you can only resort to blog posts, documentation, or guessing, more than likely you don't know enough about the topic to be a good answerer. There really is a way to see through the surface of a question and answer it in a way that feels less opinionated. Ultimately, it's a maturity thing. You can respond to something in a negative way based on its face value or see through to the spirit of it.